# How to avoid the "incompatible type" error of the 'mypy' module for operating a variable which may be assigned different types of values?

Tags: python

I have a question about the 'mypy' module. It can be demonstrated in the following code:

```
from typing import Union

def f(data: Union[str, bytes]) -> Union[str, bytes]:
    try:
        result = ' '.join(('abc', data))
    except TypeError:
        jointer = ' '.encode('utf-8')
        result = jointer.join(('abc'.encode('utf-8'), data))
    finally:
        return result
```

The code above should work properly. But the 'mypy' module will report the following errors for the line 5 and the line 8:

```
test.py:5: error: Argument 1 to "join" of "str" has incompatible type "Tuple[str, Union[str, bytes]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"  [arg-type]
test.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "bytes", variable has type "str")  [assignment]
test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "join" of "bytes" has incompatible type "Tuple[bytes, Union[str, bytes]]"; expected "Iterable[Union[bytes, Union[bytearray, memoryview, array[An
y], mmap, _CData, PickleBuffer]]]"  [arg-type]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

What is the proper way to rewrite this snippet of code to get rid of these error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with thus idea to get rid of the error messages from 'mypy'. I used the 'Generic' class from the 'typing' module to guarantee the function `join` has arguments of the same type.

The code below is the I refactored version from the code above:

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T", str, bytes)

class Converter(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, encoding: str):
        self.encoding = encoding

    def get_data_of_proper_type(self, data: Union[str, bytes]) -> T:
        functionToConvertData = {"UTF-8": {str:   lambda data: data,
                                           bytes: lambda data: data.decode("UTF-8", "backslashreplace")},
                                 "BYTES": {str:   lambda data: data.encode("UTF-8"),
                                           bytes: lambda data: data}}[self.encoding][type(data)]
        return functionToConvertData(data)

def f(data: Union[str, bytes]) -> T:
    converter = Converter[T](encoding = "UTF-8")
    dataEncodedProperly: T = converter.get_data_of_proper_type(data)
    jointer: T = converter.get_data_of_proper_type("")
    dataToBeJoined: T = converter.get_data_of_proper_type("abc")
    result: T = jointer.join((dataToBeJoined, dataEncodedProperly))
    return result
```

I am not sure if this is a good solution. I think the downsides of it are that, firstly, the revised version may have a lower performance than the previous one and that, secondly, the revised version does not look pythonic to me (since it violates the "Ask forgiveness not permission" philosophy).

Comment: I agree with your AFNP remark. I think what you and I are both struggling with is: How to keep `mypy` happy when there's a `try`? When we _know_ there might be type trouble and we already have it handled. Your `dict` approach is nice enough, might pose some maintenance hassles when new folks are added to the project. The approach I had in mind was a couple of `if isinstance(...):`, since mypy is good at such proofs. It knows we definitely have `str` in _these_ lines and `bytes` in _those_ lines. Would defining a `StrOrBytes` class maybe help? Minor style item: in 3.11 `str | bytes` is allowed.

Comment: @J_H Thank you very much for your reply and suggestion. I will try to implement the ` StrOrBytes `  class in my code as you suggested. And if I succeed, I will share my answer here.